# How to use spring data pagination with squiggly and spring boot?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data

I'm referring to the sample [here](https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly-java/tree/master/examples/spring-data-jpa-hibernate) with squiggly that support partial responses. I need to have partial responses and pagination. So I have written another method to return hotel list and code is given below.

In HotelRepository Class

```
  Page<Hotel> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

In HotelService Class

```
Page<Hotel> findHotels(Pageable pageable);
```

In HotelServiceImpl Class

```
@Override
public Page<Hotel> findHotels(Pageable pageable) {
    return hotelRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

In SampleController Class

```
@GetMapping("/hotellist")
@ResponseBody
public Page<Hotel> hotelist(Pageable pageable) {
    return this.hotelService.findHotels(pageable);

}
```

Once a request is sent as follows, a return the intended results.

```
http://localhost:8080/hotellist?page=1&size=5
```

But when a request is made as follows nothing returns an empty response, i.e. "{}".

```
http://localhost:8080/hotellist?fields=name
```

p.s. - I didn't change any other code line from the sample. Problem might be in the "Squiggly.init" method, but could not figure out a way.

How to tackle this?

Comment: how does you springboot app class look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set default value for your pageble if not passed at controller level to work

Add this to your controller request mapping

```
   @RequestParam(value="page", defaultValue = "0", required = false) int page, 
@RequestParam(value="size", defaultValue = "10", required = false) int size
```

Please add controller layer for more accurate response